# Invoke-WebRequest and Hebrew characters

Tags: powershell, hebrew

I already tried the reghack for PS to support Hebrew characters. I can type Hebrew no problems but for some reasons characters containing Hebrew returned from Invoke-WebRequest are in gibberish (see the following screenshot).

[image]

Here's the site URL I'm attempting to query:
https://www.hometheater.co.il/vt278553.html

Update:
It looks like the content-type being returned is ALWAYS of charset Windows-1255 which is probably the issue.

Comment: This might be only a visualisation issue. Have you tried writing the content to a file? You can do that e.g. as Invoke-WebRequest $muUrl | Set-Content output.txt

Comment: Just tried it. Same thing - gibberish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be not only an issue of having to specify the encoding but also that the shell cannot display the encoding correctly. If you specify the encoding to a file and edit it with a decent text editor (not Notepad but e.g. Notepad++), then you will be see that it has parsed it correctly.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.hometheater.co.il/vt278553.html" -ContentType "text/plain; charset=Windows-1255" -OutFile content.txt
```

We can also test that the in-memory presentation is correct by reading it and writing it to another file:

```
Get-Content .\content.txt | Set-Content test.txt
```

Comment: Have you verified this? I'm getting the exact same thing even through Notepad++.

Comment: Actually the first line worked out fine. The re-encoding you did messed it all up.

Comment: Hi, I made a small fix so that the 2nd line should work now as well (it was before only working due to my environment). The purpose of the 2nd line is to prove that the PowerShell object itself is OK as well.